# How to include a jquery function within a window.open

Tags: jquery, telerik-grid, popupwindow

In order for my print preview to 'accept' the styling, i need to include a function within my popup that i'm using to print:

The function i'm using to print is:

```
 $('#printPersonnel').click(function () {
            var data = document.getElementById('personnelTable').outerHTML;
            var mywindow = window.open('', data);
            mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>NORA Loading</title>');
            mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:49573/Content/Site.css">');
            mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:49573/Scripts/examples-offline.css">');
            mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:49573/Scripts/kendo.rtl.min.css">');
            mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:49573/Scripts/kendo.common.min.css">');
            mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:49573/Scripts/kendo.dataviz.default.min.css">');
            mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:49573/Scripts/kendo.dataviz.min.css">');
            mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:49573/Scripts/kendo.default.min.css">');

            mywindow.document.write('</head><body>');
            mywindow.document.write(data);
            mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');

            mywindow.document.close();
            mywindow.focus();
            mywindow.print();
            mywindow.close();
            return true;
        });
```

However, I need to include a `$(document).ready` function in order to add this formatting correctly (i'm using telerik UI grid).

This means that I would need to include script tags in my document.

My problem lies with trying to add a closing script tag (it sees itself as part of the parent page, instead of within the function).

Any suggestions as to how I could achieve this functionality?

---

I'm trying to print everything within a certain table tag, which is formatted on document ready to be viewed as a telerik grid on page load

---

**Edit**

My issue is with the closing tag of mywindow script:

```
 mywindow.document.write('});');
 mywindow.document.write('</script>'); //issue with this line/seen as esc sequence (i think)
```

[image]

Comment: Could you provide a code with including a `<script>` tag? Can't get  the problem.

Comment: Well, I am able to make`mywindow.document.write("<script>(function(){alert('1');})();</script>");` work, may be problem lies inside `$.ready` function body, syntax error or something?

Comment: `Unterminated String constant` is all I get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use backslash with the end script tag.

```
mywindow.document.write("<script>(function(){alert('1');})();<\/script>");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split `</script>` into parts, so it won't be interpreted as a closing tag:

```
mywindow.document.write("<script>(function(){alert('1');})();" + "<" + "/script>");
```

Comment: @A.Wolff you're right. Encoding `<` is even a better approach (IMHO).